# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Charts.framework/Chart Reason: image not found Xcode 9.1 Crashes at Runtime

Tags: xcode, charts

I am getting following error.Please help if anyone is having an idea.I have tried all the solutions but still facing same error.

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Charts.framework/Charts
>     Referenced from: /Users/adaptteq2017/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/18393604-6D9B-4427-85A2-E0DB4F71DF0D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7FE7854D-35F1-4DE4-9049-DA7D936A903F/ezSchool.app/ezSchool
>     Reason: image not found

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue.

Follow this process:

1. Remove the Chart frame work..
2. Check Chart Framework add in General-> Embedded Binaries + --> ChartFramework.
3. Add ChartFrame Work in General-> LinkedFrameworks
4. Build Phase--> Click on + --> Copy File select FrameWork
5. Add Chart.FrameWork in it.
6. Clean n Build.

It Works for me.